# getting error ParserError: Expected type name function

Tags: solidity

I am new in solidity and trying some small code however I am getting error which I could not find.

I am trying below code

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.6.0;

contract property {

    uint public value;
    string public location;
    //address public owner
    constructor(uint  _value, string _location) public {
          value = _value;
          location = _location;          
    }

    function setval(uint _value) public{
        value = _value;

    }

function getloc1() public pure returns(memory string) {,<--- getting error here
    return location;
  }
}
```

Error---

```
ParserError: Expected type name
function getloc1() public pure returns(memory string) {
                                       ^----^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you meant `string memory`, not `memory string`.

Comment: Thanks@smarx  to edit my question, I will take care next time. Also the error has been remove from line 18 however new error come which is in line 8 constructor(uint _value, string _location) public as TypeError: Data location must be "memory" for parameter in function, but none was given.
    constructor(uint _value, string _location) public {
                             ^--------------^

Comment: `string memory _location`

Comment: Thanks@smarx for help, I know its was not up to level query however I am trying best and one day I will also  contribute community.

Answer (score 0):

1. use string memory and remove the comma(,) from the {}.

Comment: If you answer a very old question, you should provide more details that existing answers.

Comment: yeah sure , i'll