# I read the description, but I don't understand it. Thank you for every day

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, remix, solidity-0.6.x

> ParserError: Expected type name function execfunct

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.05;
abstract contract AionClient is Aion, Context, Ownable{
using SafeMath for uint256;


address private AionAddress;
constructor(address addraion)  public{
    AionAddress = addraion;
}





function execfunct(address to, uint[] memory value, uint[] memory gaslimit, bytes calldata 
data) external virtual returns (calldata) {
require(msg.sender == AionAddress);
return to.call{value:value}{gas:106000("(gaslimit)(data)")};
}


receive () external payable {}

}
```

---

```
function execfunct(address to, uint[] memory value, uint[] memory gaslimit, bytes calldata 
data) external virtual returns (calldata)
```

I don't understand this part, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use the following order in variables: type arg_name storage.

Thus it should be `uint[] value memory`

Relevant StackExchange question: [getting error ParserError: Expected type name function](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/64170/getting-error-parsererror-expected-type-name-function)